# How to use already known var without argument?

Tags: javascript

Please help me. In this code, I get 5 instead of 10... Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
b=function(){
alert(a);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="b" onclick="c()">ok</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
var a=5;
c=function(){
var a = 10;
b();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/gJNme/)

Comment: change `var a = 10;` to `a = 10;`. You don't want to declare a new `a` inside that function, you want to reference the existing `a` in the outer scope.

Comment: it's a pity that I can't put the reputation

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you will get 5 because the 'a' is defined in two places inside function c() and for global scope as well.

Since the function b doesn't have any Local variable named a it is referring global one whose value is 5;

fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/T8grU/

```
var a=5;
b=function(){
alert(a);
}


c=function(){
 a = 10;
b();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use the keyword "var" you're declaring it as a local variable. So, you're not changing the global "a" variable, you're defining a new one locally to your "c" function.

Answer (score 0):

When you say `var` you basically reset the variable. Remove the `var` in the c function. It's being defined as a local variable to the function!

```
c=function(){
    a = 10;
    b();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
b=function(){
alert(a);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="b" onclick="c()">ok</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
var a=5;
c=function(){
a = 10;
b();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can remove `var` keyword from second declaration, just like this

```
c=function(){
a = 10;
b();
}
```

see result at [codepen.io](http://www.codepen.io/anon/pen/GLyfj)